# Can someone explain this exponent simplication ? $a^4 \equiv a^{2014} \pmod{31}$

Tags: number-theory

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835177/157291) and I am not sure I get how $a^4$ got introduced here:

> Hence, $a^4 \equiv a^{2014} \equiv −1 \pmod{31}$.

Can anyone explain that simplification?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, $31$ is prime, and for every nonzero residue $\alpha$, you get $\alpha^{30}=1$. Result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You have that $2014 = 30 * 67 + 4$.  So $a^{2014} = a^{30 * 67} * a^{4}$.  But since $a^{30} \equiv 1 (\text{ mod } 31)$, $ a^{30 * 67} \equiv (a^{30})^{67} \equiv 1^{67} \equiv 1  (\text{ mod } 31)$ you finally get that $a^{2014} \equiv 4 (\text{ mod } 31)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^{31}\equiv a\pmod{31}$, we also have $a^{30}\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, so that
$$ a^{2014} = a^{2010}a^4 = (a^{30})^{67}a^4\equiv a^4\pmod{31}.$$